# When subclassing AVPlayer, is there a more direct way to know when a player item ends, than using notification center?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, tvos

When using `AVPlayer`,

the only way I know to detect the end of a video being reached,

is to use the **notification**, just as you would when detecting the end of a video from the view controller. Eg,

```
class FancyAVPlayer: AVQueuePlayer {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
           selector: #selector(innerEnd),
           name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func innerEnd() {
        print("AVPlayer subclass, tape ended")
    }

    override func insert ..etc
    override func remove ..etc
}
```

I have always wondered, there must be a more sensible way to do this, by overriding something in AVPlayer.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

In `AVFoundation`, the notification `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` is indeed the common and recommended way to detect when a video playback has reached its end.

Overriding methods in `AVPlayer` or `AVQueuePlayer` to detect the end of playback without using Key-Value Observing (KVO) or notifications isn't supported directly by the API.

Comment: I fear that this is probably the correct answer, bbp !  Good one.  I'll wait a day or two before ticking, as is traditional, someone else may have some info.

Answer (score 0):

you can build one for yourself:

```
class CustomPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    override init(asset: AVAsset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: [String]?) {
        super.init(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(didFinishPlay),
            name: Self.didPlayToEndTimeNotification,
            object: self
        )
    }

    @objc func didFinishPlay(_ notification: Notification) {
        print(#function) /* Perfotm actions here */
    }
}
```

You can go further and pass the action from outside like:

```
class CustomPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    func addFinishAction(on queue: OperationQueue? = nil, action: @escaping (Notification) -> Void)  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: Self.didPlayToEndTimeNotification,
            object: self,
            queue: queue,
            using: action
        )
    }
}
```

So you can add the action from the outside like:

```
let item = CustomPlayerItem(url: playerItemURL)
item.addFinishAction { notification in
    print(notification) /* Perfotm actions here */
}
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
```

⚠️ Don't forget to remove observers when you done. For example you can do something like:

```
class CustomPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {
    ,,,

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: You know what, that's exactly what we do, Mojtaba!  :)  As I mention the only way I know to do it is using a Notification.  It looks like there *is no* lower level call, no public one anyways.  This sample code will be hugely useful to people.